How to copy all datasets from one library to another, but skipping already copied datasets, in SAS
I wanna copy all existing datasets from one library to another, but skipping the datasets that I have already copied, without needing to specify the names of the previously copied datasets.
The context is the following: there was an issue in the first time that I was copying the library and the proccess was halted in the middle. I am doing a security backup of many libraries and this is an issue that happens often. Last time this happened, I specified all previously copied datasets in the exclude statement. But is there a way of SAS detecting the already existing datasets in the output library and skipping them from being copied again?
The code I used:

%macro BACKUP;
%do year=1983 %to 2000;

options compress=yes;
proc copy in=jobs&year. out=backup&year. memtype=data;
*exclude tmp_: data1 companies links education;
run;

%end;
%mend;
%BACKUP;



You can use the NOREPLACE option to prevent overwriting existing members in the destination library.
options noreplace ;

proc copy in=jobs&year. out=backup&year. memtype=data;
*exclude tmp_: data1 companies links education;
run;

options replace ;


You can do this two ways: you can exclude datasets that already exist in BACKUP or you can select datasets that do not exist in BACKUP. Either one will work. It is better to use an inclusion method because we can prevent it from running PROC COPY unnecessarily if the same datasets are already there.
We'll do this using a SQL to merge dictionary.members onto itself: one where we look at datasets in jobs, and one where we look at datasets in backup. We'll subset it so that we only have datasets in jobs but not backup using an exclusive left join.
From there, read every dataset into its own macro variable. We do this instead of reading it into one long delimited macro variable is because the size of a single macro variable can only be 65,534 characters. If there are a ton of datasets, it could exceed this limit.
We can use the :var1- trick in SQL to dynamically create sequential macro variables per row. You can also do this with a DATA Step, but the SQL way might be a bit more understandable.
%macro backup;
    options compress=yes;

    %do year=1983 %to 2000;
        proc sql noprint;
            select jobs.memname, count(*)
            into :dsn1-, :n
            from (select memname 
                  from dictionary.members 
                  where libname="JOBS&year" AND memtype='DATA'
                 ) as jobs
            LEFT JOIN
                 (select memname 
                  from dictionary.members 
                  where libname="BACKUP&year" AND memtype='DATA'
                 ) as backup
            ON jobs.memname = backup.memname
            where missing(backup.memname)
            ;
        quit;
            
        %if(&n > 0) %then %do;
            proc copy in=jobs&year. out=backup&year. memtype=data;
                select %do i = 1 %to &n;
                           &&dsn&i
                       %end;
                ;
            run;
        %end;
            %else %put NOTE: All datasets in JOBS&year are in BACKUP&year..;
    %end;
%mend;
%backup;

